# Angular 2 Auth Guard Re-Direct To Home page

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way to re-direct to my home page if the route is blocked by AuthGuard.

For example, if the user goes to www.my-example.com/user while not logged in, he will be blocked by auth guard, I want that user to be re-directed back to the home page. At the moment it just shows a blank page.

```
// app.routing.ts
const APP_ROUTE: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', },
{ path: '', component: UserLayoutComponent, children: [
    { path: 'user', loadChildren: 'app/user/user.module#CalenderModule' },
    ]
}];

// user.routing.ts
const USERR_ROUTE: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];

export const userRouting = RouterModule.forChild(USERR_ROUTE);
```

Comment: it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/1208/routing-3-0-0/7648/create-the-guard#t=201703151321281233562

Comment: Yes it is possible. Post code showing how you've implemented your AuthGuard.

Comment: Problem solved. A simple this.router.navigate was the solution. Thanks gents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import{Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class  AutoGuard implements CanActivate{
  constructor(private _router : Router){}
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    if(/*some condition*/){
        this._router.navigate(['/some_url']);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```